# Play against console versions with PC?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12, now that the game is finally the same on PC and consoles, is it possible to play against people on other platforms (XBOX, PS3) with my PC version or are those on completely different servers?

Comment: I can't definitively answer this, but chances are it's a No. It's a very short list of games that have cross-platform play when it comes to consoles. And even then, it's only every PS3 to PC, and Xbox 360 to PC, never all 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at all. I can tell you for sure that the servers are totally different and the servers that host PSN and Xbox Live won't connect with each other due to PSN and Xbox Live being totally different consoles and companies. For example on the PS3 you can only connect with people using PSN so they must have to have a PS3. The EA ID is only for tracking stats that can be viewed online. As the comment above says it will only ever be Xbox > PC or PS3 > PC.

Comment: You said that matches between different consoles are impossible, but it's not quite clear from your answer if PC to console is possible in Fifa12.

Comment: As stated no due to PC not being able to connect to PSN or Xbox live which is used for matchmaking